# Why side menu not collapsing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Created a side menu with the help of HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and JavaScript. The menu now works fine: If you click on (Student Management) then the menu will show. If you click on (Invoicing Management) then (Student Management) Will hide and (Invoicing Management) will show. The problem: Both menus are closed as of now. keep clicking simultaneously (Fast clicks) on (Student Management) then Click on (Invoicing Management) (One Click) then Click back on (Student Management). Both menus will show. Can someone explain why both menus are shown? How to correctly fix the bug with code examples. Expected one menu to show per time.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapsed').on('click dblclick', function (ev) {
        if ($('.active').length > 0 &&
            !$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $('.active').trigger("click");
            $('.active').removeClass("active");
        }
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $('.sub-menu li').on('click dblclick', function (ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

```css
.sideMenu {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #2e353d;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #e1ffff;
}

.sideMenu ul, #navbar ul,
.sideMenu li, #navbar li {
    list-style: none;

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #e1ffff;
}
    .sideMenu ul,
    .sideMenu li {
        line-height: 35px;
    }

.sideMenuRightArrow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px
}

.sideMenu ul .active,
.sideMenu li .active {
    border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
    background-color: #4f5b69;
}

.sideMenu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.sideMenu li .sub-menu li.active {
    color: #d19b3d;
}

.sideMenu ul .sub-menu li,
.sideMenu li .sub-menu li {
    background-color: #181c20;
    border: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

    .sideMenu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
    .sideMenu li .sub-menu li:hover {
        background-color: #020203;
    }
/*    .sideMenu ul .sub-menu li:before,
    .sideMenu li .sub-menu li:before {
        font-family: Fontawesome;
        content: "\f105";
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }*/
.sideMenu li {
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}

    .sideMenu li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #e1ffff;
    }

        .sideMenu li a i {
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }

    .sideMenu li:hover {
        border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
        background-color: #4f5b69;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #navbar {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .sideMenu {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    #navbar {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .sideMenu {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SMS_Online</title>
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 
    <main role="main" class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="col-xs-03">
            <div class="sideMenu">
                <div class="menuItems">
                    <ul class="">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i>Main Dashboard<span class="arrow"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#studentsSubItems" class="collapsed">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>Student Management<i class="fas fa-chevron-down float-right sideMenuRightArrow"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="studentsSubItems">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Student Main
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Register Student
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#invoicingSubItems" class="collapsed">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>Invoicing Management<i class="fas fa-chevron-down float-right sideMenuRightArrow"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="invoicingSubItems">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Invoicing Main
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Create an invoic
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement this yourself. Bootstrap already has an accordion that does this. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: @dantheman Thank you for clarifying that bootstrap has accordion to use which seems to be a quick fix to escape the problem but not tackling it. I want a fix so if I come across it again I know how to fix. do rate you for the suggested to use accordion.

Comment: why you use two version of bootstrap cdn ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your javaScript logic is wrong. I have added one extra class `menu` beside `collapsed` class like this at two places.

One,

```
<li
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#studentsSubItems"
  class="collapsed menu"
>
```

Another,

```
<li
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#invoicingSubItems"
  class="collapsed menu"
>
```

And modified your javaScript code like this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
        $(".menu").not($(this)).addClass("collapsed");
        $(".menu").not($(this)).attr("aria-expanded","false");;
        $(".menu")
          .not($(this))
          .find(".sub-menu")
          .removeClass("show");
    });
});
```

And this works perfectly as you want.